# Proof of implication for inference

Tags: logic

I'm gonna prove if $x$ is not free in $\psi$, then $(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\models (\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi) $.

Here is my argument:

According to definition of rule of inference of QR, if $x$ is free, then one can deduce $(\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi)$ from $\phi \rightarrow \psi$. Mathematically: $(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\vdash (\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi) $. Furthermore, from soundness theorem, we know that, if $a \vdash b$ then $a \models b$. So, according to truth of $(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\vdash (\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi) $, $(\phi \rightarrow \psi)\models (\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi) $ holds.

Is this sort of argument valid?

If one says (you must prove that "if $x$ is free, then one can deduce $(\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi)$ from $\phi \rightarrow \psi$", I don't know the argument for that.)

UPDATE:

$(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \models (\exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi)$

$(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \models \neg(\exists x \phi) \vee \psi$

$(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \models (\forall x (\neg \phi)) \vee \psi$

$(\neg\phi \vee \psi) \models (\forall x (\neg \phi)) \vee \psi$

$(\neg\phi \vee \psi) \models (\forall x (\neg \phi)) \vee \psi$

By universal instantiation:

$(\neg\phi \vee \psi) \models (\neg \phi) \vee \psi$

Which is true.

[image]

Comment: What is QR? Also, did you mean to say that $x$ is not free in $\phi$?

Comment: @Bram28; Please find the update.

Comment: I do not think that it works... The soundness theorem relies on the soundness of the rules. Thus, you have to show that the rule is sound according to the semantical specifications of the system.

Comment: @Roboticist Can you please post that picture of the problem statement that you had up yesterday? Thanks!

Comment: @Bram28: Here you are.

Comment: @Roboticist Thanks!  So, if you follow the discussion I had with Mauro, you'll see that I had this wrong: depending on how exactly you define the semantics, apparently it *is* ok for $\phi$ to have $x$ as a free variable! And, unless you have a proof system with inference rules that allow free variables, that means you really need to take that semantical approach to prove what you want ... which is exactly what Mauro did.

Comment: @Bram28: Your discussion is indeed full of educational points for me. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

See [**Ch.2.5 Soundness**](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA55) : our rules of inference will preserve truth, i.e. for a rule $⟨Γ,θ⟩ : Γ⊨θ$.

And see [**Th.2.5.2**](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA56) for the proof that the rules are sound.

The Exercise asks to prove that the [second QR rule](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA53) :

> $\langle \{ \phi \to \psi \} , (\exists x) \phi) \to \psi \rangle$, $x$ not *free* in $\psi$,

preserves truth.

Assume a structure $\mathfrak A$ such that $\mathfrak A \vDash (\phi \to \psi )$, i.e. for any assignment function $s$ : $\mathfrak A \vDash (\phi \to \psi )[s]$.

We have to prove that : $\mathfrak A \vDash ((\exists x)\phi \to \psi )[s']$, for every $s'$.

*Case (i)* : If $\mathfrak A \vDash \psi[s']$, it's done.

Thus, consider :

*Case (ii)* : $\mathfrak A \nvDash \psi[s']$.

We want that $\mathfrak A \nvDash (\exists x)\phi[s']$, i.e. that $\mathfrak A \nvDash \phi[s'[x|a]]$ for some $a \in \text {dom}(\mathfrak A)$.

But we know that : $\mathfrak A \vDash (\phi \to \psi )[s]$ for every $s$, and thus also : $\mathfrak A \vDash (\phi \to \psi )[s'[x|a]]$.

But $x$ is not *free* in $\psi$ and thus $s'$ and $s'[x|a]$ agree on the free variables of $\psi$; thus, from $\mathfrak A \nvDash \psi[s']$ we have also : $\mathfrak A \nvDash \psi[s'[x|a]]$, for some $a$.

This, due to  $\mathfrak A \vDash (\phi \to \psi )[s'[x|a]]$ above, implies that : $\mathfrak A \nvDash \phi[s'[x|a]]$, for some $a$, i.e.:

> $\mathfrak A \nvDash (\exists x)\phi[s']$.

Answer (score 0):

So two things:

First, you are trying to prove that this logical entailment holds on the basis of an existing inference rule plus soundness. OK, that should work ... If you know that this specific inference rule is sound.  Do you know that?  I mean, yes, there are many sound systems of logic (indeed, presumably most systems of logic are sound) .. But just because we are presented with some system and some inference rule doesn't mean it is sound; we would have to prove that it is sound, which means we would need to prove exactly the entailment you want to prove. So unless someone told you that this specific inference rule is sound, this would become a circular argument. Indeed, I suspect that the whole goal of the exercise you are presented with is to prove the very soundness of this very inference rule, meaning that your approach would indeed be circular (you'd assume the proof system that includes this inference is sound in order to prove that this inference rule is sound). So, you most likely need to use formal semantics to prove this.

Second, about the actual soundness of this inference rule (or the validity of the entailment) ... I must say it looks very weird: it says that $x$ is not free in $\psi$ .. But the inference rule really doesn't do anything with $\psi$; instead, it quantifies the $\phi$. Meaning that if $x$ is a free variable in $\phi$, then we have a big problem since that would mean that we have a different set of variables free between the left hand side and the right hand side... in a way, we would be comparing apples with oranges! So, I think a mistake was made here, and that they should have said that $x$ is not a free variable in $\phi$ .. And then the entailment actually holds!

**EDIT**

OK, so I had this last part wrong: with a proper semantics, you *can* make sense of (and prove!) $\phi \rightarrow \psi \vDash \exists x \phi \rightarrow \psi$, even if $\phi$ contains free variables (see Mauro's answer).

Comment: To get rid of such circulation, how should I prove that inference rule is sound?...

Comment: @Roboticist You will need to go into formal semantics, considering what it takes for an interpretation to set some statement to true. Logical entailment means that for all interpretations that set the implying statement(s) to true, they will set the implying statement to true as well.

Comment: Could you please see `UPDATE 2`?... I hope I'd just solved the issue without the circulation.

Comment: But you are starting with what you are trying to prove ...

Comment: And you said the approach is not so reliable... Now, I'm trying to find a right one, based on your signal.

Comment: @Roboticist Ok, good luck! I'll check back in tomorrow to see how you did.

Comment: It is not "weird" at all; it is $(\exists \text E)$ of Natural Deduction in disguise: if $\psi$ follows from $\phi[y/x]$, then it follows from $\exists x \phi$, **provided that** $y$ is not free in $\psi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see that, but my worry was about $\psi$: if $\psi$ contains $x$ as a free variable, I do think something funny is going on. I also note that you talk about $\psi[y/x]$ ... was that given in the problem statement?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Sorry, I got the greek symbol wrong :(  I meant my worry is about $\phi$: what if $\phi$ contains a free variable $x$?

Comment: $x$ must be free in $\phi$, otherwise the rule is trivial...

Comment: Basically, the rule is : $\lnot \phi(x) \lor p \vdash \forall x \lnot \phi(x) \lor p$ [I've used the prop variable $p$ to emphasize the fact that $x$ is not free in it]. We have to consider the "fine details" of the semantics : the rule preserves *truth* and we have that a formula is *true* in a structure ($\mathfrak A \vDash \phi(x)$) **iff** it is satisfied in that structure for **every** assignment function $s$. So by cases : $p$ *true* : done; $p$ *false*, we must have $\mathfrak A \vDash \lnot \phi(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Right, if $\phi$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable it's all good.  But the problem statement never made this clear, and it did not use $p$' to suggest it either .. instead it used $\phi$'s and $\psi$'s, which on the face of it look like any arbitrary formulas. Indeed, when it explicitly says that $\psi$ does not contain $x$ as a free variable, but it doesn't say that for $\phi$ ... then it obviously opens the door for $\phi$ to contain $x$ as a free variable.  This has all along been my complaint about this problem statement (which, unfortunately, the OP since removed).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093812/derivation-question-for-predicate-calculus ... let's call it a truce :)

Comment: I've re-linked (into my answer) the page with the original formuation of the two QR rules...

Comment: Agreed, but... It is not the same: the question you are referring to amounts to : $\exists x (A \to B) \vdash (A \to B)$. And as per my comment at the OP, I'm quite confident that it is **not** sound. Consider : $\exists x (x=0 \to 0=1) \vdash \text {???} (x=0 \to 0=1)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, your reference makes it clear that some term is substituted for any free variables in $\phi$ ...  that was *not* said in the problem stated by the OP. Again, it's too bad the OP removed it. I'll ask him if he can put it up again so you can see I am not hallucinating.  And yes, for that old post I did assume A and B did not contain $x$ as a free variable, and of course I should *not* have just assumed that, because indeed you get nonsense if that's not true, which was exactly my concern with the original problem in this post. I really think we are on the exact page here!

Comment: Correct: the rule is fine written that way: the only thing to be specified must be : "$x$ not free in $\psi$". The proof must be general, and thus it has to consider the case $x$ free in $\phi$, because if not we have nothing to prove : $\phi \to \psi \vDash \phi \to \psi$. But this does not means that the rule is not sound if $x$ is not free in $\psi$ **and** $\phi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh ... OK, so now I am getting concerned maybe I *am* getting something wrong. I thought that $x=0 \rightarrow 0=1 \vDash \exists x x = 0 \rightarrow 0=1$ would be just as nonsensical as $\exists x(x=0 \rightarrow 0=1) \vDash x = 0 \rightarrow 0=1$ ... am I wrong about this?

Comment: Again, "relative to" the specified proof system + semantics; see def of [logical implication](https://books.google.it/books?id=3BVjCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA36).

Comment: The semantical specs consider formulae *tout court*, i.e. also free vars; in this case, we have that $\mathfrak A \vDash \phi(x)$ **iff** $\mathfrak A \vDash \phi(x)[s]$ for **every** $s$. And the def of $\gamma \vDash \psi$  is : for every $\mathfrak A$, if $\mathfrak A \vDash \Gamma$, then $\mathfrak A \vDash \psi$.

Comment: Thus, consider $\mathbb N$: of course, $\mathbb N \vDash ∃x(x=0→0=1)$... it is enough to consider $s(x)=1$ and we have $\text F \to \text F$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA OK, I think I am beginning to see ... so I could define a formal semantics such that $x = 0 \vDash \exists x \: x = 0$?

Comment: But what about $\mathbb N \vDash \text{???} (x=0→0=1)$ ? is it true that $\mathbb N \vDash \text (x=0→0=1)[s]$ for **every** $s$ ? Of course not; it is enough to consider $s(x)=0$ and we have $\text T \to \text F$.

Comment: **YES**, because, according to the semantics : $\mathbb N \vDash (x=0)$ iff $\mathbb N \vDash (x=0)[s]$ for **every** $s$ which means simply that $(x=0)$ is read as $\forall x (x=0)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ah! So $\mathbb{N} \vDash x = 0 \lor \neg x = 0$ would also be true then, right?

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic... but I've spent some years to understand why some proof system use the rule $\phi \vdash \forall x \phi$ also if it is well known that $Px \to \forall x Px$ is **not** valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Please, no apologies!  I should be the one to apologize!  With this semantics, you are right and I was wrong: I now see how $\phi$ can indeed have free variables $x$ in the problem statement.  Thank you for teaching me!!

Comment: Yes; of course we can "eradicate" the problem - see [van Dalen well-known textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA67) - simply defining the basic semantical relations only for *sentences*. In this case, the trick is : $\mathfrak A \vDash \phi =_{def} \mathfrak A \vDash \forall \overline x \phi$ where $\forall \overline x \phi$ is the *universal closure* of $\phi$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Right ... I have only ever seen that kind of semantics, hence my confusion. Or actually: I have seen semantics where you make sense of $P(x) \lor Q(x) \vDash Q(x) \lor P(x)$ (so it didn't have to be sentences, as long as they use the same free variables) but I had never encountered a semantics where you can have $P(x) \vDash \forall x \: P(x)$, i.e. where the sets of variables can be different.

Comment: In the end (refer to your answer to the previous (the linked one) post) : if $x$ is not free neither into $A$ nor in $B$, then trivially $\exists x (A \to B) \vDash A \to B$. If instead $x$ is free in $B$, your application of rule (iv) is *illegal* (but the level of "collaboration" of the OP is so low that your work is much more than needed) :-)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA :) Thanks again for sharing your knowledge, I really appreciate it!